# How to differentiate column with duplicate data in Python CSV library

Tags: python, csv, import

```
import csv

def compare_and_replace(csv1_file, csv2_file):
    # Load CSV1 data into a list of dictionaries for easy lookup and preservation of order
    csv1_data = []
    with open(csv1_file, 'r') as file1:
        reader1 = csv.DictReader(file1)
        csv1_data = list(reader1)  # Convert reader1 to a list of dictionaries

        # Iterate over CSV2 and update CSV1 data if a match is found
        with open(csv2_file, 'r') as file2:
            reader2 = csv.DictReader(file2)
            for row in reader2:
                color = row['Variants']
                image_url = row['[CS]Color']
                for data in csv1_data:
                    product_name = data['Product Name']
                    if color in product_name:
                        sku = data['Product Code/SKU']
                        for item in csv1_data:
                            if item['Product Code/SKU'] == sku and item['Item Type'] != '  SKU':
                                item['Product Image File - 1'] = image_url

                                # Update the product name with the new image URL
                                updated_product_name = product_name.replace("#0057A6", image_url)
                                data['Product Name'] = updated_product_name
                                break  # No need to continue searching

        # Search in CSV2 for values in "Main Image" and import them into ImageImport.csv
        with open(csv2_file, 'r') as file2:
            reader2 = csv.DictReader(file2)
            for row2 in reader2:
                image_url = row2['Main Image']
                if image_url:
                    if not csv1_data[0]['Product Image File - 1']:
                        csv1_data[0]['Product Image File - 1'] = image_url
                        break

                    # Update the Image URL in ImageImport.csv
                    csv1_data[0]['Product Image File - 1'] = image_url
                    break

        # Import data from CSV2 under the column "Description" into ImageImport.csv
        with open(csv2_file, 'r') as file2:
            reader2 = csv.DictReader(file2)
            for row2 in reader2:
                description = row2['Descriptions']
                if description:
                    csv1_data[0]['Product Description'] = description
                    break

        # Insert "Y" in row[0], column with the header "Product Image Is Thumbnail - 1"
        csv1_data[0]['Product Image Is Thumbnail - 1'] = "Y"

        # Write the updated data to a new CSV file "ImageImport.csv"
        fieldnames = reader1.fieldnames
        with open('ImageImport.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
            writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerows(csv1_data)

# Usage example
compare_and_replace('CSV1.csv', 'CSV2.csv')
```

This is what the current code looks like. Essentially it is tasked to read CSV1 and CSV2 and combine data within certain cells. The image uploaded is of CSV1 before the script is run that will import any data.

I'm trying to write something in Python that will replace the data below each Product ([CS]Color... ) however the issue is there are many duplicates. For example [CS]Color=CHINA PEARL may appear several times within the CSV. How can I target each specific product set individually and replace only the [CS]Color=CHINA PEARL under the desired product, in this case it would be DETAILED ELEGANCE PATTERN. Currently the code is a blanket statement that is replacing an matches it finds at all so there are multiple rows "Product" being replaced at once with the same data.

What kind of solution is there to this? Can I somehow write something that loops through each "Product" row finding the name of the product under "Product Name" and then only replacing the data per product?